# Set Content of ListView according to the Screensize

Tags: android, listview

I want to automatically fit listview content according to the screen size i.e If listview have five data and screen is large even this five data should display in whole screen.Is this possible or not if possible then how.

```
 <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/moreBtn"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etSearch"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
        </ListView>
```

Comment: android:fillViewport="true" is not attribute of listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.as per your question you have same size for each row is better UI.you can do it but its not right way to fill whole screen.and what about when only one row and you try to fill whole screen ?

in short its not better to fill listview in whole screen.

if you want to do that then set your row layout size to `fill_parent`,but its makes visible only one item.so you have to check how many row in list and then divide by screen height and set row size programmatically.

Comment: Yeah @Samir exactly this i have to do........Actually in this app listview will have at least five data....So i have to do that....

Comment: One thing more @Samir how can i devide height of layout.......i'm not getting how to do .....please suggest me.....\

Comment: try to search set view height in andorid